# Cannot SSH to EMR node to access Zeppelin

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to use Zeppelin notebook but I couldn't, I tried to enable SSH (configured Security groups for Master inbounds, Downloaded and configured putty, add foxy proxy to chrome and uploaded the xml file. The steps can been seen in the photos:

Cannot enable SSH:

[image: cannot enable ssh]

Step 1:

[image: steps 1]

Step 2:

[image: steps 2]

Step 3:

[image: steps 3]

PuTTy:

[image: putty]

Foxy Proxy:

[image: foxy proxy]

Foxy Proxy XML file:

[image: foxy proxy xml file]

Comment: It looks like you successfully connect via PuTTy. How did you then try to connect to Zeppelin?

Comment: I try http://ec2-157-175-98-150.me-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8890/ but couldn't connect.

Comment: although putty looks connected you can see that ssh is not enabled (in the first image)